# Laravel query logging missing update queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, logging, eloquent

I have this code in a controller (Laravel 5.6):

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$foo->update($data);
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

The problem is that in the dump there is no `update` query. I know the `update` command is running (I can see the updated data in the database). What am I missing?

Comment: What is $foo?  Does $data contain different data?  If $foo is a model and $data doesn't have any changes, update() won't actually run a query.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent or Query Builder?

Comment: `$foo` is a model, `$data` contains different data. Looking before and after, I see the update has worked. But nothing is dumped out.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya Eloquent

Comment: Are you using multiple database connections?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No.

Comment: Does the log work with other queries (e.g. `SELECT`)?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, `SELECT` statements are being shown.

Comment: What about `INSERT` and `DELETE` queries?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks for your help - it's resolved itself now, though I can't pinpoint what resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$foo->update($data);
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Personal choice, but I would even modify it a bit more to:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$foo->update($data);
print_r(\DB::getQueryLog());
die();
```

You might like the output better.

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try Query Builder:

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
DB::connection('your-connection')->update($data);
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

If that doesn't work out, you might want to check [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) out.

Comment: Eloquent's doing a bit of work behind the scenes so I can't use Query Builder unfortunately. The Laravel DebugBar also shows no `update` query.

Comment: I understand your love for Eloquent. You could just try other things for debugging purposes. At least that would help rule out certain variables and narrow the possible causes.

Comment: Can we see what your dd() produces?

Comment: You are right of course. I will try it and get back to you later with the results (no time now). `dd()` produces nothing.

Comment: Ok mate. Standing by.